# Dual boot option not showing Instead showing GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I dual booted one of my friends laptop with ubuntu and windows 10. When i first restarted, it was restarted successfully and there was boot options and i choose linux as my OS. But after a while when my friend tried to boot into windows, it showed grub instead of boot options. How can i fix this and show boot options instead of GRUB at startup?